# Why are IBOutlet Properties declared in a class extension?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, interface-builder

When I create a new single view application, the UIViewController file that is generated has an extension (I think it's an extension) in the implementation file.

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

//...

@end
```

And the convention seems to be that IBOutlets are declared as properties inside this extension. Why is this? What kind of behavior does this result in that is different from declaring it in the header file interface?

Comment: It's architecture. Don't let other classes see the internals. The whole point of controller is to have control over the views it owns. Other classes shouldn't even see the views.

Comment: Oh. Is that the only reason? Security? Sorry for the simple question, might be obvious to everyone. I'm a novice, so it seems that a lot of the questions I ask are apparent to everyone else.

Comment: It has absolutely NOTHING to do with security. It's architecture - good code and separation of concerns. Let other classes see a clean interface, don't let them see the internals.

Comment: I thought that was what code security was? Hiding internals so it can't be messed with externally?

Comment: No, hiding internals is done for better architecture. Programmers can still access them using reflection so it has nothing to do with security. Obj-C doesn't contain any syntax that could prevent programmers from accessing your internals. Still, making them invisible from the exterior is good for architecture.

Answer (score 2):

Properties in the header files are public, property declarations in the implementation files are private. It's up to you to choose. You can connect them directly from the interface builder into the desired file.
I can't understand your concern about extension - this code is fine. Could you explain this? (i can't comment - too less reputation, sorry)

Comment: I believe `@interface ViewController()` is a class extension. IBOutlet properties are usually declared here, and you can only drag an object to this extension to declare the IBOutlet. Dragging to the header file won't work. I'm wondering why extensions are used to declare IBOutlets.

Comment: Dragging to the header file interface does work, try to open the interface builder and the header file at the sime time in the split view, this is very convenient to drag IBOutlets. I just googled and it seems that yes, interfaces are somewhat called extensions.

Comment: Oh, now that I try it, I see that it works. Didn't work before. I wonder what the use case would be for declaring IBOutlets in the header file. Extensions are a bit different from the regular interface in header files, it's a special kind of category, I think.

Comment: For example if you subclass your class, then your subclass can only access the property if it is declared in the header file.

Comment: @Adriano Replace word "access" with word "see". Headers don't limit what you can access. They limit only what you can see.

Comment: @Sulthan i totally agree, thanks. I could delete my comment, but it seems i can't edit it anymore. There's a 5min time limit as far as i know.

Comment: @Sulthan Could you clarify how this is true? I thought if a property was not declared in the header file, there was no way to access them externally, how would you access properties that are declared in an implementation file? You mentioned something about reflections in another comment?